# multiple calls of another JS function inside a function causes an error

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

Uncomment //fn in the alg() function and run the code and it will no longer return 0
What is causing this error?? can't I call a function multiple times inside another function definition?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script>
function factorial(b)
{
factorial=1;
for(b; b > 1; b--)
{
factorial =b*factorial;
}
return factorial;
}
function alg(n, k)
{


 fk = factorial(k);
 //fn=factorial(n);


return 0;


}


</script>


<body>
<script>
write=alg(5,2);

document.write(write);
</script>
```

Comment: So you're using global variables with the same name as the function, and it's not working for you? Try this -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/fd9un/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the variable `factorial`, which is clearly supposed to be a local variable inside the `factorial()` function, is not declared as a local variable. Fix is simply to declare it using the `var` keyword:

```
function factorial(b)
{
    var factorial=1;
    for(b; b > 1; b--)
    {
        factorial =b*factorial;
    }
    return factorial;
}
```

Without the declaration of `factorial` as a local variable inside the scope of the `factorial()` function, `factorial` just references the `factorial()` function object, which has global scope because it is declared with the syntax `function factorial(){...}` at the top level of the script.

So when the code inside `factorial()` changes this `factorial` reference to point to a number value, the second `factorial()` call will fail because the global variable `factorial` now points to a number, not the `factorial()` function.

Global variables are widely considered to be one of the [bad parts](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do) of javascript. This is a good example of why!

**UPDATE**

For clarification, this issue is not confined to strictly global variables - it's just a general issue of function name scope. When a function is declared like `function name(){...}` that name has scope within the function and its parent. It's just that here, the parent context happens to be the global context.

Comment: It's far from obvious :) Answer just edited to clarify that this issue is not some special behaviour of global variables. When a function is declared like `function name(){..}` this the name is visible within its scope and the scope of the parent. The parent of `factorial()` happens to be the global context here, but the issue and the fix would be exactly the same if all this code was in the scope of a parent function `parent()`, in which case `factorial()` function name would have scope within the `parent()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your variable factorial of "function factorial(b)" to something else like factorial1. Variable name is being conflicted with function name

```
    function factorial(b)
{
factorial1=1;
for(b; b > 1; b--)
{
factorial1 =b*factorial1;
}
return factorial1;
}
```

Comment: that's not the issue apparently, but it really is worth practicing to name variables and functions differently